# Javascript: loop function with var in the function name

Tags: javascript

In my `HTML` file I have two lists with values and I'm writing a `JavaScript` function to drag and drop values from one list to another. When the user clicks on one value in the list and drags it to another value, I save the new array with values of the list to the input hidden field.

Everything is working but the problem is that I have 70 of such pairs of lists on the one page so I don`t want to write 10 separated functions for each list to perform drag and drop functionality.
I want to make for each loop of the function.

Dag and drop function is working right with for loop

```
 $(function() {
  for( var variable = 0; variable < 70; variable++ ) {
   var li1 = "#sortable1" + variable;
   var li2 = "#sortable2" + variable;
   var li3 = li1 +',' + li2;
   $(li3).sortable(
   {
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    } 
   ).disableSelection();  
  } // close for
});
```

And function that should save new values of list into hidden text fields is not working with a `foreach` loop

```
for( var x = 0; x < 70; x++ ) {
   var var1 = "form ul#sortable1" + x +" li";
   var var2 = "form ul#sortable2" + x +" li";
   var var3 = var1 +',' + var2;

    $(var3).on('li propertychange click', function(index) {

       var sortable1 = "ul#sortable1" + x +" li";
       var sortable2 = "ul#sortable2" + x +" li";

       var row_order1 = "row_order1" + x;
       var row_order2 = "row_order2" + x;   

       var selectedLanguageone = "selectedLanguageone" + x;
       var selectedLanguagetwo = "selectedLanguagetwo" + x;   

        var selectedLanguageone = new Array();
        $(sortable1).each(function(index) {
            selectedLanguageone.push($(this).attr("id"));
        });
        document.getElementById(row_order1).value = selectedLanguageone;

        var selectedLanguagetwo = new Array();
        $(sortable2).each(function(index) {
            selectedLanguagetwo.push($(this).attr("id"));
        });
        document.getElementById(row_order2).value = selectedLanguagetwo;


    })(x);

}
```

Maybe it is hard to understand my code by the main problem is that I need to have variable in the name of my function and use the same var inside the function.

Comment: *"...problem is that I need to have variable in the name of my function and use the same var inside the function."* What makes you think you need to do that?

Comment: Try to step trhough your code with the debugger of your browser (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Tools/Debugger) and see at which point it does not do what you expect. I suspect some minor mistake or a logical error.
If you can't step because you have an error message. Add that error message to your question.